# RegEx - match all periods except the period preceded by 'single capital letter'

Tags: regex

Any ideas on how to remove all periods from a large text document, by using a regex on a text editor for the following example:

```
J.      don't match
F.C.    don't match
word.   match
Word.   match
WORD.   match
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try something like this: `\w{2,}?\.`

You can go to [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HYuefU/1/) and try it for yourself with more test strings to get the one you want. If you want to actually exclude the periods you can use a capturing group like so: `(\w{2,}?)\.`

Comment: I was really close! I was missing that `+?`.
Thank you

Comment: It fails for `d.`

Comment: This is true, however he didn't add that as a possible test case so I assumed he didn't want to match lowercase single letters before a period.

Comment: Why not shorten it to `\w{2,}?\.`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too,

```
(?<!(?<=^|[^A-Z])[A-Z])\.
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/161)

Answer (score 1):

Below regex matches multiple word characters or single non-capital string followed by `.`:

```
((\w{2,})|([^A-Z]))\.$
```

Comment: Thank you! A valid answer too. However lowercase for me doesn't matter.